# Multiple conditions for one column after group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to group by Id then applying condition for the grouped results.

| Group | LastName | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smith | Jane |
| 1 | Smith | John |
| 2 | Doe | Beth |
| 2 | Doe | Jane |
| 2 | Doe | Jay |
| 3 | Ward | Bill |
| 4 | Adams | Beth |
| 4 | Grimes | Jane |
| 4 | Gag | Smelly |

Here in the first Name column after group by if it contains both Jane and Beth under first name column then I have to select that Id

Expected results

| Group | LastName | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Doe | Beth |
| 2 | Doe | Jane |
| 2 | Doe | Jay |
| 4 | Adams | Beth |
| 4 | Grimes | Jane |
| 4 | Gag | Smelly |

Comment: please show your attempt

Comment: Select id from table group by group having firstname=Jane and firsname = bath

Comment: [edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically need in this case a group by where the first name is found in a per group and the count = 2.  THEN join back to the original table for all people within those given groups.

```
select
      YT.Group
   from 
      YourTable YT
   where
      YT.FirstName in ('Jane', 'Beth') 
   group by
      YT.Group
   having
      count( distinct YT.FirstName ) = 2
```

The count of DISTINCT would prevent a false result if you had a Jane Doe and a Jane Smith in the same group.  This would be a distinct count of 1 since there is no Beth in this example.  So, now from this result, you can get the rest by making the above a prequery

```
select
      YT2.*
   from
      ( select
              YT.Group
           from 
              YourTable YT
           where
              YT.FirstName in ('Jane', 'Beth') 
           group by
              YT.Group
           having
              count( distinct YT.FirstName ) = 2 ) PQ
         JOIN YourTable YT2
            on PQ.Group = YT2.Group
```

Feedback post-answer

You probably need to post from you comment as a NEW question.  As a relatively newbie, I wont bust your chops on it though :)

To clarify, it SOUNDS like you are looking for an "AND NOT 'Beth'?   Implying the minimum of Jane, but could be any number of other names as long as they are NOT Beth?  If that is the case, I would restructure the inner pre-query (alias PQ) to something like

```
      ( select DISTINCT
              YT.Group
           from 
              YourTable YT
                 LEFT JOIN YourTable NoBeth
                    on YT.Group = NoBeth.Group
                    AND NoBeth.FirstName = 'Beth'
           where
                  YT.FirstName = 'Jane'
              AND YT.Group NOT IN
                  ( select YT3.Group
                       from YourTable YT3
                       where YT3.FirstName = 'Beth' ) ) PQ
```

Here, the first criteria is getting JANE, but then notice the NOT IN following.  The subquery is looking only for groups where there is a Beth firstname.  So the NOT IN is telling query to EXCLUDE any where Beth is associated with a given group.  Don't need a group because the primary consideration is Jane.  So, even if you have MORE than one "Jane" in the group, the DISTINCT will return just one instance of a given Group.

Comment: it works as expected thank you @DRapp

Comment: I have another scenario where I Have to select Group Id if the group has "jane" as the first name then only i have to select the group if that group contains 'jane' and 'beth' then no selection if 'jane' and 'jay' selection to be done how to approach

Comment: @Ajay, see revision to expand answer to your secondary follow-up

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `FirstName` is fixed only for `Jane` and `Beth` then

```
SELECT GroupId, LastName, FirstName
FROM test_table
WHERE GroupId in (
    SELECT GroupId FROM test_table WHERE FirstName in ('Jane', 'Beth')
)
```

**NOTE:** I have updated `Group` with `GroupId` in order to remove conflict with `default` SQL keywords.

[Fiddle Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=111eb7bc08e3b80bcbdba1bf50521919)

Comment: it works fine but it's not giving expected results and even my question is not proper editing now please check question .. thankyou for the response and for fiddle it helped me to test the scenerio's